# Ideas for using a computer as a 'display' for public use

Tags: security, internet-explorer, firefox

I'm going to be presenting a website at a show/expo, and I'm wondering what the best way to go about it is...

My plan so far is - leave my laptop (hidden, secured, folded over) connected to an external monitor with a usb mouse. Idea being, I'll leave an internet browser open and let people click about and explore.

What I don't want, is for them to do anything but this...

I'm aware FF has a few plugins ([Public Fox, for example](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/public-fox/)) and IE has a kiosk mode, but before I choose something, I was interested to see what everyone else uses for this purpose? I'll not be too far away at any time, but it's just for extra piece of mind.

Any input welcome,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Keith says, whatever you do, you want to provide the most basic OS you can, so you could try:

- [Linux Kiosk](http://kiosk.mozdev.org/)

This will help to minimise your attack surface. Then you'll want a locked down browser (ie whitelist the websites you want them to be able to access) or you'll find it being used as an attack tool or for surfing pr0n before you know it!

Oh, and lock it down with a Kensington - as you'll be not too far away and that will put off the casual laptop thief.

Answer (score 3):

I've used a thin client or locked-down Linux machine before.  A VM guest on your laptop with only a few items installed could work, or one of the kiosk VM guests out there.